# how to store recent values in a variable in java programming?

Tags: java

In my java program,I need to store the recent values in a variable and my code is as shown below

```
public class Exmp2 
{

        int noOfInstances;
    public Exmp2() 
    {
        noOfInstances++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Exmp2 e1=new Exmp2();
        System.out.println("No. of instances for sv1 : " + e1.noOfInstances);

        Exmp2 e2=new Exmp2();
        System.out.println("No. of instances for sv1 : "  + e2.noOfInstances);
        System.out.println("No. of instances for st2 : "  + e2.noOfInstances);

        Exmp2 e3=new Exmp2();
        System.out.println("No. of instances for sv1 : "  + e3.noOfInstances);
        System.out.println("No. of instances for sv2 : "  + e3.noOfInstances);
        System.out.println("No. of instances for sv3 : "  + e3.noOfInstances);
    }
}
```

My output should be 1 2 2 3 3 3
but am getting 1 1 1 1 1 1 
can you give solution?

Comment: Use static int noOfInstances;

Comment: use `static` keyword for `int noOfInstances`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare your `noOfInstances` variable as `static`.

```
static int noOfInstances;
```

Since its not `static`, for every `new Exmp2()` a `noOfInstances` is created for that instance, with the default value as `0`.

Answer (score 3):

you havew to declare `noOfInstances` to be static

```
    static int noOfInstances;
```

otherwise every new instance create by `new` will have its own value of `noOfInstances`, beginning at 0 again

Answer (score 2):

noOfInstances should be declared static. For example:

```
static int noOfInstances;
```

This might be an interesting read. It should have an example with a similar situation as yours:

[static keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

In short, static literally makes a variable shared among instances of a given class.
If you have a variable that is not static every instance will have its own private value for that variable. While a statically declared variable will have the same value in all instances of a class.

Answer (score 2):

The variable should be declared `static`.

**Why?** Because presently your variable `noOfInstances` is *not static* and for each instance of your class you create noOfInstances variable will also be created and always the value will be 1.
So on declaring it static it is shared between all the instances of this class and will have the correct value.

**Static variables are created when the class is loaded and are shared across all the instances.**

Answer (score 2):

Make `noOfInstances` **static** like given below,

```
static int noOfInstances; // static are shared among all objects created.
```

and no need to call `e1.noOfInstances` instead you can call **Exmp2.noOfInstances**

Instance (non-static) variable are copied in Objects whereas static variables are not copied in object. static are at the class level. Every object can see it.

Answer (score 2):

You Should declare your variable `int noOfInstances;` as `static`, in your code the instances are taking default value 0.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare you variable as **static** : `static` variable always stores the recent values,its static variable would store in `static pool`

```
static int noOfInstances;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do `new Exmp2();` then `noOfInstances` assigned to 0 as you are instantiating a new Object, Make `noOfInstances` as `static` so that its scope shifts to class level.

Answer (score 1):

See the below example on how to use the static variable for instance count

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

public class Exmp2 {

    static int noOfInstances;

    public Exmp2() {
        noOfInstances++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("No. of instances at this point "
                + Exmp2.noOfInstances);
        Exmp2 e1 = new Exmp2();
        System.out.println("No. of instances at this point "
                + Exmp2.noOfInstances);
        Exmp2 e2 = new Exmp2();
        System.out.println("No. of instances at this point "
                + Exmp2.noOfInstances);
        Exmp2 e3 = new Exmp2();
        System.out.println("No. of instances at this point "
                + Exmp2.noOfInstances);
    }
}
```